# Solving design involving multiple inheritance and composite classes in c++

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, composite, ambiguity

I have struggled with this design problem for some time. I will do my best to explain what I am trying to do and the various approached that I have seen, what I am trying and why.

I work in a scientific computing environment where I deal with the same kinds of objects repeatedly. Imagine a  galaxy which contains solar systems, each solar system contains planetary systems and each planetary system contains moons. To this end I think of the situation as a “has a” situation, and thus I have used composition to give the galaxy access to its solar systems, and each solar system access to the planetary systems which have access to their moons: each category being its own class.

It is often the case that the various problems I am working on contain different types of data about these objects. And, as different types of data become available I can do certain things with my objects. So, when I have data type 1 available to me I create the following classes

```
class GalaxyOne { /* … */ };
class SolarSystemOne { /* … */ };
class PlanetOne{ /* … */ };
class MoonOne{ /* … */ };
```

And when I have data type 2 available to me I create

```
class GalaxyTwo { /* … */ };
class SolarSystemTwo { /* … */ };
class PlanetTwo{ /* … */ };
class MoonTwo{ /* … */ };
```

The composite aspects of each class are dealt with by using container variables such as vectors which contain pointers to the contained classes. For example, within each Galaxy class one would find.

```
class GalaxyTwo{ /* … */
protected:
std::vector<SolarSystemTwo*> solarSystems;
/* … */
};
```

The difficulty comes when I want to combine classes into higher-order classes.

```
class GalaxyOneTwo: public GalaxyOne, public GalaxyTwo{
/* Additional methods */
};
```

However, this creates a problem of ambiguity in the solarSystems vector because  GalaxyOneTwo would have a version of it from GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo. Furthermore, the vectors it inherits contain pointers to objects which are not of type SolarSystemOneTwo, which would be required. So, I thought I could create a template class which all of my objects inherit from where I put all of my container variables.

```
template<MoonT,PlanetT,SolarSystemT>
    class PrimitiveGalaxy {
    private:
        std::vector<SolarSystemT*> solarSystems
};

class GalaxyOne: public PrimitiveGalaxy <MoonOne,PlanetOne,SolarSystemOne>{
    /* No longer defining any container variables for composition */
};
```

This approach works very nicely for those fundamental Galaxy types (GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo). However, whenever I try to create the combined galaxy type I get all kinds of ambiguity.

```
class GalaxyOneTwo: public GalaxyOne, public GalaxyTwo, public     PrimitiveGalaxy<MoonOneTwo,PlanetOneTwo,SolarSystemOneTwo>{
    /* … */
};
```

I get ambiguity if I use solarSystems within any method defined in GalaxyOneTwo because it is defined three times, once through each inherited version from GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo and a third time through GalaxyOneTwo.

I can get rid of this ambiguity by being specific and using

PrimitiveGalaxy::solarSystems

each time to refer to the proper vector, but this is not desirable because it requires a LOT of extra typing and syntax.

I have considered using friendship between each galaxy type and the primitive galaxy but this requires a similar level of verbose writing.

I have a hunch that namespaces may simplify my writing of code but I am not sure how to define the namespace such that within a namespace defined for GalaxyOneTwo that any reference to solarSystems is a reference to 
PrimitiveGalaxy::solarSystems

Edit:

Please note, the only difference between GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo is NOT the type of the class contained in solarSystems. There are many differences because each class deals with different data relevant to the galaxy. Thus, I create different classes which will have different state variables, getters and setters for those state variables and methods to calculate and print data. solarSystems is an example of the feature which is giving me problems thus that is what I have described here. When GalaxyOneTwo is created it will use the same data that is used for GalaxyOne and for GalaxyTwo and thus I want to inherit all of their variables and methods. And because the data can be combined in different ways I need to create new methods for that within GalaxyOneTwo. These are some of the many differences that lead me to use inheritance. That being said, it is the container variables that allow for composition that give me problems. Within each solarSystem class there will be a similar vector giving them access to their planets, and so on and so forth.

Edit:

For a question specifically dedicated to my design philosophy here in general (as opposed to this questions emphasis on trying to resolve my current design attempt) see the following link:
[Guidance in creating design for multiple-inheritance composite classes in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15121365/1618297)

Comment: What IS a GalaxyOneTwo supposed to be? A collection of tho different types of galaxies, or a common interface (or implementation???) of the two? What kind of operations would you like to do on a GalaxyOneTwo?

Comment: As I tried to describe above, GalaxyOneTwo is a galaxy which not only has access to the member functions of GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo thereby allowing it to process the same data, it adds additional functionality in its ability to combine the various kinds of data traditionally available only to GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo so as to perform more complicated data analysis.

Comment: No, I wonder: What IS the thing you try to model using inheritance? A kind of galaxy that has all of the types of solar systems found in galaxy one and galaxy two? When I ask for what kind of operations, I mean a concrete example, such as, getting the total mass of the galaxy, luminosity, star count and so on. If you give examples of what kind of combined capability GalaxyOneTwo should have you may get better answers.

Comment: If the set of data1 includes location data and data2 includes luminosity data then GalaxyOneTwo (and off of its contained SolarSystemOneTwo, PlanetOneTwo and MoonOneTwo classes) would have access to the location and luminosity data which would allow it then to calculate relative luminosity from say a given solar system's location to another.

What I am suggesting is that it is only in the getters and setters of the conainer variables which contain pointers to the contained classes that are giving me trouble.

Comment: The inheritance is a way of allowing me to combine functionality. My projects often involve novel combinations of data and thus I want to be able to combine my more fundamental classes into more complex classes as the need arises and only have to write the new functions that relate to the novel combination of data while retaining the old functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could change data models to implement something component based. Each component could contain the same state information you mentioned for the different types. And you could inherit virtual functions

```
class Galaxy
{
  // galaxy information

  // Virtual functions shared among galaxies
  virtual void sharedGalaxyFunction() = 0;

  // Vector containing all solar systems in this galaxy
  std::vector<SolarSystem*> solarSystems_;
};

class SolarSystem
{     
  // solar system info

  // Virtual functions shared among all solar systems
  virtual void sharedSolarSystemFunction() = 0;

  // Vector containing planets
  std::vector<Planets*> planets_;
};

// etc for planets...
```

You could then inherit the different types of solar systems or galaxies to create the special cases and fill out the virtual function calls

```
class CoolSolarSystem : public SolarSystem
{
  // Special variables

  // Fill in the virtual function
  void sharedSolarSystemFunction();
};
```

You could then populate the containers inside the different base types with the pointers to your special types. You should be able to avoid a cast back to the special type if the virtual function calls handle enough of that information.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach require redefining those same functions many times as more complicated composite SolarSystem classes are build when new data is used?

Comment: Will this work if only some CoolSolarSystems implement the shared function? What I am imagining is that as I create more composite functions I define the specialized functions as I need them in the specialized function cases and then in the SolarSystem class just add a virtual function to be defined later. But, for method1 say only CoolSolarSystem1 implements that function. Is it okay if CoolSolarSystem2 leaves it undefined?

Comment: If the function isn't a pure virtual function then that could definitely work. You would have to implement some simple functionality for the base class or just leave it blank if you don't want the function to do anything for "unimplemented" objects.

Comment: As it turns out, I was able to implement something like this with success. I will soon be posting the code as an additional answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to have one `class Galaxy`, one `class SolarSystem`, etc. And yours `GalaxyOne`, `GalaxyTwo`  `SolarSystemOne`, `SolarSystemTwo` etc. are only different objects instantited from these classes.

```
class SolarSystem { /* … */ };
class Planet{ /* … */ };
class Moon{ /* … */ };

class Galaxy{ /* … */
 public: // Galaxy(...?...){for (...) {read data??; solarSystem.push_back(createSolarSystem(data)); }
 void AddSolarSystem(SolarSystem* ss){solarSystem.push_back(ss);}
 protected:
   std::vector<SolarSystem*> solarSystems;
   /* … */
};
```

....

```
Galaxy GalaxyOne, GalaxyTwo;
```

If we have no way to use this simple aproach... Lets see yours:

```
class GalaxyOneTwo: public GalaxyOne, 
                    public GalaxyTwo, 
                    public PrimitiveGalaxy<MoonOneTwo,PlanetOneTwo,SolarSystemOneTwo>{
    /* … */
 using PrimitiveGalaxy<MoonOneTwo,PlanetOneTwo,SolarSystemOneTwo>::solarSystems;
 GalaxyOneTwo(){solarSystems.reserve(10);}
};
```

Here you have three private vectors: (using `using` you make it direct accesible)

```
std::vector<SolarSystemOne*   > GalaxyOne::solarSystems;
std::vector<SolarSystemTwo*   > GalaxyTwo::solarSystems;
std::vector<SolarSystemOneTwo*> solarSystems; //GalaxyOneTwo::solarSystems;
```

Is this what you need? Make it protected?
[image]

Comment: No, this is not the case. Perhaps I was not clear from my description. I deal with various kinds of data that require different variables and methods to work with them. GalaxyOne is a class of galaxy which is built to handle a certain set of data. GalaxyTwo handles a different set of data and thus has different variables and methods for data processing. GalaxyOneTwo is if I have both of the original kinds of data and thus I want the original variables and methods from GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo is well as new variables and methods that handle the synthesis of the data available.

Comment: Yes, I have a question: the type of SolarSystem is the only diference betwen the Galaxys types? GalaxyOneTwo will have just some SolarSystem of clas One plus others of type Two?

Comment: No, that is not the only difference. Where you see the ellipse is where other differences are. There are significant differences. GalaxyOne deals with a set of data, call is data1. There are variables and methods related to data1 which you find in GalaxyOne. GalaxyTwo deals with a set of data, data2 which is not at all the same as data1. Thus, GalaxyTwo has many other differences. I am not having difficulty with those variables and methods that are not container variables containing objects like SolarSystemOne or MoonOne etc so I did not include those.

Comment: Please read paragraph 3 and the two related code snippets to understand why I am not dealing with different objects of the same class.

Comment: @vckngs7: is there any data types or methods that these two do share?

Comment: Those data types or methods that they do share the inherit from PrimitiveGalaxy

Comment: I think your method of utilizing the "using" descriptor will work. I have a large number of such variables and methods. Is there such a way as to declare a namespace for GalaxyOneTwo that gives direct access to these variables and methods?

Comment: I have tried to remove ambiguity with the "using" statement, this has worked for me only for methods thus far. I still get an ambiguity error when applying it to a variable.

Comment: @vckngs7 Can you post the error, the declaration, the using and the actual use of the variable with error? (I still think there is a way to somewhat simplify your design with "normal" inheritance... but not trivial way)

Comment: @qPCR4vir I managed to get something like the following to work:

using PrimitiveGalaxy<MoonOneTwo,PlanetOneTwoSolarSystemOneTwo>::getSolarSystems;

I am able to remove any ambiguity to a call to the getter function std::vector<SolarSystemT*>* getSolarSystems();
found within the PrimitiveGalaxy class.

However, with the same format I am unable to remove ambiguity of the call to solarSystems

using PrimitiveGalaxy<MoonOneTwo,PlanetOneTwo,SolarSystemOneTwo>::solarSystems;

I get an error like:

error: reference to ‘solarSystems’ is ambiguous

Comment: I am open a redesign but I find that I am either having difficulty describing my needs and thus many of the suggested alternate approaches would not meet my needs or I do not fully understand the new approaches and how they can in fact meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract out the common stuff between the 'One' and 'Two' versions of stuff into a set of 'Common' base classes:

```
class GalaxyCommon {
    // all the common stuff between GalaxyOne and GalaxyTwo including
    std::vector<SolarSystemCommon *> solarSystems;
    ...
};

class GalaxyOne : public virtual GalaxyCommon {
    // all the stuff that is unique to model One
};

class GalaxyTwo : public virtual GalaxyCommon {
    // all the stuff that is unique to model Two
};

class GalaxyOneTwo : public virtual GalaxyOne, public virtual GalaxyTwo {
    // should be complete
};
```

Note the use of `virtual` -- required to get properly working multiple inheritance.

Comment: I have already abstracted out the common stuff, hence the use of PrimitiveGalaxy. My problem is in fact, not one of the diamond problem because PrimitiveGalaxy is a template class and each time it is inherited from each class a different version of it is created for the relevant templates. My challenge is to find an efficient way to remove the ambiguity in referring to the members of PrimitiveGalaxy from GalaxyOneTwo.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question right:

1. There are several types of galaxies that can have nothing at all in common between them.
2. The same goes for Solar and planetary systems.
3. You would like to combine collections of these different types and yet have full access to the underlying methods for that type.

This sounds like a case for [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html)

So now your Galaxy is:

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
typedef std::vector<boost::any> collection;
class Galaxy
{
   collection SolarSystems;
   public:
   ...methods...
};
class SolarSystem
{
   collection PlanetarySystems;
   public:
   ...methods...
};
class PlanetarySystem
{
   collection Moons;
   public:
   ...methods...
};
```

Ofcourse, this doesn't really do anything, but does allow you to group them. In order to do anything useful (call a method) you will still have to detect the type, cast it to that type and then run the code you need to.

However, what this does allow you to do is to group objects of different types together, which I think is what you're after with GalaxyOneTwo. Here is [more information](http://sandfly.net.nz/blog/2009/12/the-c-boost-libraries-part-6-boostany/) on how you can do that.